# Access country on woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, country, shipping-method

With the code below, I am able to change the display of specific shipping methods full labels on WooCommerce cart and checkout pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'custom_shipping_labels', 10000, 2 );

function custom_shipping_labels($label, $method){   
    $shpmethod = $label;

    if(strpos($shpmethod, 'Express Shipping') !== false){
        $shpmethod = str_replace('Express Shipping',' test express lbl',$shpmethod);
    }
    elseif(strpos($shpmethod, 'Free Standard Shipping') !== false){
        $shpmethod = str_replace('Free Standard Shipping',' test free lbl',$shpmethod);
    }
    return $shpmethod;       
}
```

Now I need to access the customer selected county inside that custom function hooked in `woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label` filter hook.

Is it possible to get the customer selected country in that hooked function?

Answer (score 2):

To get the selected shipping country you can use one of those:

- from WC_Session data `WC()->session->get('customer')['shipping_country']`.
- or [`WC()->checkout->get_value('shipping_country')`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Checkout.html#_get_value)
- or from WC_Customer data: [`WC()->customer->get_shipping_country()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Customer.html#_get_shipping_country).

**For testing purpose**, here with the code below, selected *(or customer)* billing country **code** is displayed with each shipping method full label:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'custom_shipping_labels', 10000, 2 );
function custom_shipping_labels($label, $method){
    // Get selected shipping country value (country code) 
    $shipping_country = WC()->checkout->get_value('shipping_country');

    // If shipping country is empty, we get it from customer data
    if( empty( $shipping_country ) ) {
        $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    }
    return $label .' ('.$shipping_country. ')';
}
```

Now in your code you can use `$method->label` **to target each** defined shipping method label string, which is more efficient. So your code will be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'custom_shipping_labels', 10000, 2 );
function custom_shipping_labels($label, $method){
    // Get selected checkout shipping country value (country code) 
    $shipping_country = WC()->checkout->get_value('shipping_country');

    // If shipping country is empty, we get it from customer data
    if( empty( $shipping_country ) ) {
        $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    }

    if ( $method->label == 'Express Shipping' ) {
        $label = str_replace( $method->label, __('test express lbl'), $label );
    }
    elseif ( $method->label == 'Free Standard Shipping' ) {
        $label = str_replace( $method->label, __('test free lbl'), $label );
    }
    return $label;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Now you can use the selected shipping country as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use [`WC_Customer::get_shipping_country()`](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_customerget_shipping_country/)

> https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Customer.html

```php
function custom_shipping_labels( $label, $method ) {
    // DEBUG
    //echo '<pre>', print_r($label, 1), '</pre>';
    //echo '<pre>', print_r($method, 1), '</pre>';

    // Get shipping country
    $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();

    // DEBUG
    echo $shipping_country . '<br>';

    if ( $shipping_country == 'BE' ) {
        echo 'Yeey' . '<br>';
    }

    if( strpos( $label, 'Express Shipping') !== false) {
        $label = str_replace( 'Express Shipping',' test express lbl', $label );
    } elseif( strpos( $label, 'Free Standard Shipping') !== false) {
        $label = str_replace( 'Free Standard Shipping',' test free lbl', $label );
    }

    return $label;      
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'custom_shipping_labels', 10, 2 );
```